# Android Login with MySql and PHP

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I'm very new to android. I tried to create login app with PHP and Mysql. I referred to a source where he used a library called GenAsync.jar to avoid many coding "he said". However, i followed every bit of his instruction but unfortunately I cant login. What is the problem? Could it be because am running it on mobile device and not emulator as he demonstrated? I also use an online server but his demo used a localhost. Pls help me out? Many Thanks in advance.

```
package issa.example.com.mysqldatabase;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.kosalgeek.asynctask.AsyncResponse;
import com.kosalgeek.asynctask.PostResponseAsyncTask;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse{

    EditText etUsername, etPassword;
    Button btnLogin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                HashMap postData = new HashMap();
                postData.put("btnLogin", "Login");
                postData.put("mobile", "android");
                postData.put("user_name", etUsername.getText().toString());
                postData.put("pass_word", etPassword.getText().toString() );

                PostResponseAsyncTask loginTask =
                        new PostResponseAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, postData);
                loginTask.execute("http://mchucha.com/android/logini.php");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void processFinish(String output) {
        if(output.equals("success")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Login Successfully",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

```
PHP script text
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "mchuchac_user";
$password = "123";
$dname = "mchuchac_db";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dname);
    if (!$conn){
        die ("connection failed: " .mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    else {
        echo " connection success";
    }

?>
```

```
<?PHP 
    include_once("connection.php"); 
    if( isset($_POST['user_name']) && isset($_POST['pass_word']) ) { 
        $username = $_POST['user_name'];
        $password = $_POST['pass_word'];

        $query = "SELECT username, password FROM tbl_client ". 
        " WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'"; 

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            if(isset($_POST['mobile']) && $_POST['mobile'] == "android"){ 
                echo "success"; 
                exit; 
            } 
            echo " Login success";
        } else{ 
            echo "Login Failed <br/>"; 
        } 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Remove if (!$conn){
        die ("connection failed: " .mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    else {
        echo " connection success";
    } from your connection.php and try it again..

Comment: But even if i don't remove that code the connection works fine when i test in browser. The only problem is either in the file "logini.php" file or android code i think.

Answer (score 1):

although your question not so clear (what have you done for that fail and have the username and password value passed to php/web service) I want to try help you by do some steps to get your fail/error.

1. first, make sure the connection of DB is well.

   `$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dname);
           if (!$conn){
               die ("connection failed: " .mysqli_connect_error());
           }
       else {
               echo " connection success";
           }`
2. Check the username and password value have it passed in webservice, by echoing $username and $password.
3. If until 2nd step run well, please to debug the query by doing like this:

   `$query = "SELECT username, password FROM tbl_client ". 
           " WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";`

Run that query in mysql application (phpmyadmin for example).

Thats my explanation, hopefully it will help you.

Comment: Everything works fine until that part. And i can even insert the data in my database when i change the query to insert query. Also the app runs fine with no error in my device;except that every thing i key in it gives me "login failed". Its really a headache!.

Comment: so, you must check the condition in this line if(output.equals("success")){...}. Is that condition right, and the parameter of that method right too?

Answer (score 0):

Try my webservices of Login which i have given

**Login.php**

```
<?php
include_once('connect.php');
        error_reporting( error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE ); 


            $r_emailid = $_GET["r_emailid"];

             $r_password = $_GET["r_password"];

       $sql = "select * from admin_registration 
       where r_emailid = '$r_emailid' and r_password = '$r_password'";
         $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
       {
           $output[]=$row;

       } 

       if(empty($output))
       {
           $response['success'] =false;
           $response['message']="Invalid Login";
            print(json_encode($response));
       }

            else
            {

                 $response['Data']=$output;
                $response['success']=true;
                $response['message']="Login Successfully";

                print(json_encode($response));

            }





?>
```

**connect.php**

```
<?php

$mysql_db_hostname = "localhost";

$mysql_db_user = "root";

$mysql_db_password = "";

$mysql_db_database = "adurec";







$con = @mysqli_connect($mysql_db_hostname, $mysql_db_user, $mysql_db_password,

 $mysql_db_database);



if (!$con) {

 trigger_error('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());

}
?>
```

Comment: Hello #Garima Mishra. I tried your code. The file connect.php works fine. But when i run Login.php file it displays this error in browser window. "connection success{"success":false,"message":"Invalid Login"}". What could be a cause?

Comment: give me your details i will try it from here

Comment: Actually i want to create a login app with username and password. I got the code that i post from online lecture. The author gave a file to use as a library (he said it will lessen a burden to code a lot). I put that file inside project > app > libs. He used a localhost server and he run the app using emulator. For my case i use an online server and run the app using mobile device. However, the app can run giving no error but if i key in everything (even a correct login credentials) the app says "login failed". I may send you the files if you need to. Thanks

Comment: my database name is tbl_client with 4 attributes (id, name, username, password).

Comment: Yaa you send me the files as i am doing by this method.; if you will send me the file i will able to understand easily

Comment: Thanks will check that.. Its compulsary for you to do by this method or you can use another method to login such as JSON

Comment: Give me any Username and Password which you have inserted into database

Answer (score 0):

[image]

this response you can check

Like this you will get the output that makes sure your php side is correct you have to do on your android side

Answer (score -1):

```
**Login.java**

public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener {



    String regId = "";





    public static final String REG_ID = "regId";
    public static final String EMAIL_ID = "eMailId";

    EditText et_username, et_password;
    public Button bt_login;
    public static String Username, Password, Name;
    // Connection detector
    ConnectionDetector cd;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String URL, URLmessage;
    Animation shake;

    private boolean validEmail(String email) {
        Pattern pattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
        return pattern.matcher(email).matches();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_details);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
        addintialvalues();
        et_username.setText(SettingsFragment.getDefaults("Username", getApplicationContext()));

    }


    private void addintialvalues() {
        et_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_username);
        et_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
        bt_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_login);
        shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.shake);
        bt_login.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.bt_login:

                if (cd.isWifiAvailable() || cd.isNetworkAvailable()) {
                    // Get username, password from EditText
                    Username = et_username.getText().toString();
                    Password = et_password.getText().toString();

                    if ((!validEmail(Username))) {
                        et_username.startAnimation(shake);
                        et_username.setError("Please enter valid email");

                    } else if (Password.length() <= 0) {
                        et_password.startAnimation(shake);
                        et_password.setError("Password Should not be Empty");
                    } else if (Password.length() != 4) {
                        et_password.startAnimation(shake);
                        et_password.setError("Enter 4 Digit");
                    } else {

                        try {


                            URL = "http://localhost/mis/login.php?"
                                    + "r_emailid="
                                    + Username
                                    + "&r_password="
                                    + Password;


                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        new LoginTask().execute();

                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Check Internet.....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;


            default:
                break;
        }
    }



    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */

    public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait.....");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            // JSONArray data = null;
            String jsonstr = jParser.makeServiceCall(URL, JSONParser.POST);

            Log.d("Json url view string", jsonstr);

            if (jsonstr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonstr);
                    URLmessage = jobj.getString("message").toString();
                    JSONArray jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("Data");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jobjj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Name = jobjj.getString("r_name");
                        Username = jobjj.getString("r_emailid");
                        Password = jobjj.getString("r_password");
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Login Screen", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;

        }

        @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();

            if (URLmessage.matches("Invalid Login")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Login.....",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Password = et_password.getText().toString();
                Username = et_username.getText().toString();

                Intent k = new Intent(getBaseContext().getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(k);



            }
        }
    }
```

**JSONParser.java**

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

public class JSONParser {
    static String response = null;
    public final static int GET = 1;
    public final static int POST = 2;

    public JSONParser() {

    }

    /**
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
        return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
    }

    /**
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * @params - http request params
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {
        try {
            // http client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            // Checking http request method type
            if (method == POST) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                // adding post params
                if (params != null) {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                }

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } else if (method == GET) {
                // appending params to url
                if (params != null) {
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                            .format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            }
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;

    }
}


**Webservices of Login**

<?php

    include_once('connect.php');
    $R_emailid = $_GET["R_emailid"];
    $R_password = $_GET["R_password"];

    $sql="select * from registration 
    where R_emailid='$R_emailid' and R_password='$R_password'";
      $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

     while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {

           $output[] = $obj;

    }          
           if(empty($output))
                {
                    $response['success']=false;
                    $response['message']="user does not Exist";
                    print(json_encode($response));
                }
                else
                {
                $response['Data']=$output;
                        $response['success']=true;
                        $response['message']="login successfulll";
                         print(json_encode($response));

                }






?>


The complete demo on how to login with json with use of webservices
Refer it and if any query do ask me
Kindly abort please if you find it useful
Thank you
```

Comment: please provide some explanation to your answer